# show method called instead of destroy method in laravel datatables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I'm having an issue with the laravel's datatables plugin, when I'm trying to delete an element from my datatables list it calls a show method, making the delete impossible. Can someone explain me why it behaves like that and how to fix it ? Here is my code.

Controller :

```
public function destroy($project) {
    $project = Project::find($project);

    $project->delete();

    session()->flash('message', 'projet supprimé');

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function ajaxListing() {
    $projects = Project::select(['id', 'title']);
    return Datatables::of($projects)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($project) {
            return '<a class="data-action" href="'.route('projects.edit', $project->id).'">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="data-action" href="'.route('projects.destroy', $project->id).'">
                        <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

View :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" id="listingProjects">
    <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Titre</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
    </thead>


</table>

@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#listingProjects').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ordering: true,
            language: {
                processing: "Traitement en cours...",
                search: 'Recherche : ',
                lengthMenu: "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
                info: "Affichage de l'&eacute;lement _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
                paginate : {
                    first : '<i class="fa fa-fast-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                    previous : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                    next : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                    last: '<i class="fa fa-fast-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                }
            },
            ajax: '{!! route('datatables.projectData') !!}',
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ]
        });
    });

</script>
@endpush
```

Routes :

```
Route::any('project-data', 'Admin\ProjectsController@ajaxListing')->name('datatables.projectData');

Route::resource('projects', 'Admin\ProjectsController');
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer, the problem was in the route, we need to add an except to the resource route and create our own delete route, like that :

```
Route::get('projects/{project}/delete', 'Admin\ProjectsController@destroy')->name('projects.destroy');
Route::resource('projects', 'Admin\ProjectsController', ['except' => 'destroy']);
```

That way we just need to call the route on the link in the view.